# Info on installing

Tags: installation, upgrade, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I was thinking of installing Ubuntu on one of my computers for a test run to see how I like it, but the problem I face is that the one computer I wish to install it on isn't network ready.

There's no network card installed and I keep that computer as a safe computer away from any network connections.

The question I have is that is there an ISO I could download that contains all the necessary files for upgrading it to current, similar to the way one would download and install Windows Services Packs offline?

I realize the convenience of doing this online, but what would one do if they don't have an Internet connection

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 12.04.1 was recently released, it will contain *most* of the updates. You could install from that:

- [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)
- [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

However, there will still be some updates you're missing, and as time goes on, there will be more and more. Therefore, you may *also* want to use some offline updating method. As @Anwar has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194547/info-on-installing#comment241702_194547), we already have a question about how to do that:

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)